# Bitrise fails to install missing android tools - Fabric

Tags: android, maven, bitrise

The Bitrise step `install-missing-android-tools` is failing because it is not finding the fabric's Gradle plugin version `1.25.4`.

But as you can see [here](https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml) the version exists, also when I run `bitrise run 'dev'` the build pass as expected.

I'm out of ideas of what is happening. The step log:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (2) install-missing-android-tools                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id: install-missing-android-tools                                            |
| version: 2.2.0                                                               |
| collection: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git                |
| toolkit: go                                                                  |
| time: 2018-09-20T20:11:58Z                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
INFO[20:11:58] Start installing (golang) with apt-get       
INFO[20:11:58]  * [OK] Step dependency (go) installed, available. 
Configs:
- GradlewPath: ./Project/gradlew
- AndroidHome: /opt/android-sdk-linux
Preparation
Set executable permission for gradlew
Initialize Android SDK
Ensure android licences
Ensure required Android SDK components
Retrying...
Failed to ensure android components, error: output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Project'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.25.4/gradle-1.25.4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.25.4/gradle-1.25.4.pom'.
               > Read timed out
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 31s
error: exit status 1
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | install-missing-android-tools (exit code: 1)                  | 105 sec  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Issue tracker: ...bitrise-steplib/steps-install-missing-android-tools/issues |
| Source: ...://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-install-missing-android-tools |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: An additional info, sometimes the build runs as expected, sometimes that error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to jcenter.bintray.com - just tried to open the linked https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.25.4/gradle-1.25.4.pom and I got a 404 (not found). So even if this version exists, it seems it might not exist on jcenter. Maybe it was available on jcenter in the past but was removed?

Of course if it's available in a local cache then gradle won't fail, even if it's no longer available on the remote/url, as it can use the local cached version.

Comment: It makes sense, but there is one thing I do not understand, why sometimes the build runs as expected even in the bitrise (I do not have any cache step on bitrise)? How bitrise downloads that dependency?

Comment: @ademar111190 without the related build logs it's really hard to say. In general there's nothing specific to bitrise here, the related step just runs `gradle` commands. If you contact our support via email or the onsite chat and provide the build urls we can look into it for you.

Comment: I agree it doesn't look to be a bitrise problem because the error happens without a clear pattern. Right now it is not happening, as soon as it happens again (hopefully it doesn't happen again) I'll contact the support, thank you.